# Possible to make a script to simulate a VM Snapshot with pass-through disk? 

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, snapshot

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V and one VM with a Pass-Through disk. Naturally I can't take a snapshot (it's a limitation of Hyper-V) but can I use a scrip to the unmount disk, take a snapshot and then remount the disk?

Comment: What is the underlying storage system for that disk?  Is is it a SAN that supports snampshots?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  See Ben Armstrong's blog for information about constructing your scripts.

http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/default.aspx

My bigger question to you is why you think you need a pass-through disk?